# How do I calculate the Reynolds Number of fluid parcels around an aritrary object (with respect to CFD)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, navier-stokes

Purpose: I am trying to create my own simplified rapid CFD software for custom purposes.

Given an arbitrary object surrounded by a moving fluid (from an arbitrary direction in 3D), how would I best calculate the Reynolds number for each fluid parcel to apply the discrete Navier Stokes equation to? I cannot simplify density being constant for my purposes (compressible flow). Specifically, how would I go about finding the characteristic length and would this characteristic length apply to the whole fluid or just the object? View the image below to get an idea for what I'm asking the Reynolds Number for.

[image: Example Image]

Also, does the characteristic length for an arbitrary object change depending on the orientation it is 'seen' from?

Thanks!

[image: NS Equations]

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would I best calculate the Reynolds number for each fluid parcel to apply the discrete Navier Stokes equation to?

It does not make sense to calculate the Reynolds number for each fluid parcel. The Reynolds number depends on a characteristic length scale of the system, but there is no characteristic length scale shown for this system.

What I mean by characteristic length scale is, for example, the diameter of a pipe down which the water flows, or for example, the characteristic size of some obstruction around which the water flows.

---

Instead of working with the equations you show in your screenshot, you might want to return to the original form of the Navier-Stokes equation and just write the equations in terms of viscosity rather than Reynolds numbers.

For example, for incompressible steady-state flow with no body forces:
$$
\vec u \cdot \vec \nabla \vec u - \frac{\mu}{\rho}\nabla^2\vec u = -\frac{1}{\rho}\vec \nabla p\;,
$$
where $\rho$ is the (constant) density and  $\mu$ is the viscosity.

Comment: Question about this formula, can the density be variable or does it have to be constant for this equation to hold?

Comment: The equation holds for constant density. I used the incompressibility assumption to arrive at the equation and I assumed steady state, so the density can't vary arbitrarily. More general equations are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#General_continuum_equations